# Choose date within a range using ipywidgets Date Picker

Tags: python, datepicker, widget, ipywidgets

I need to create a widget that would allow the user to choose a date between two dates, say `datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)` and `datetime.date(2023, 12, 31)`, and from the official documentation of `ipywidgets` I could not find anything more than this:

```
date_picker = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False,
)
```

Can someone please help me add constraints to the widgets? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
start_date = widgets.DatePicker(description='Start Date', disabled=False, value = datetime.date(2021,1,1))
end_date = widgets.DatePicker(description='End Date', disabled=False, value = datetime.date(2023,12,31))
```